# In Swift, how does a method return a generic type?

Tags: swift

I want a method to return String or Int as in the method below. How to define the * type? Mind, I dont want to return a tuple, just a single value. :beer:

```
func returnsSomething(key: Bool) -> * {
    if key == true {
        return "Im a string!"
    } else {
        return 42
    }
}
returnsSomething(true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options.

---

First, you can declare your method as returning type `Any`, which will allow you to return any type you want.

```
func returnsSomething(key: Bool) -> Any {
    if key {
        return "I'm a string"
    } else {
        return 42
    }
}
```

This will work perfectly fine, but it has the downside that if you use implicit type definitions:

```
let foo = returnsSomething(true)
```

Then `foo` won't have the type of `String` or `Int`, but rather `Any`, and you're left with optional downcasting.

```
let foo = returnsSomething(true)
if let bar = foo as? Int {
    // use bar as an Int
} else if let bar = foo as? String {
    // use bar as a String
}
```

<sup>As a note, you don't actually have to use `Any` here.  For example, if you wanted to return a `UIView`, `UIButton`, or `UITableView`, you could use `UIView`, as the latter two are both subclasses of `UIView`.</sup>

---

Second, you can use method overloading:

```
func returnsSomething() -> String {
    return "I'm a string!"
}

func returnsSomething() -> Int {
    return 42
}
```

This works, but now you cannot use implicit typing *at all* with this method.  Notice that the following generates an error:

> ```
> let foo = returnsSomething()
> ```
>
> Ambiguous use of 'returnsSomething'

However, if we're explicit with the type, this is allowed:

```
let fooString: String = returnsSomething()
let fooInt: Int = returnsSomething()
```

And the compiler is perfectly satisfied.

Comment: beautiful! this thing about having 2 methods with the same name freaks my brain, but fits my purpose perfectly, cheers. :)